# How to use OnClick action buttons in R ShinyDashBoard

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I am doing sentiment analysis of twitter data using R and shiny dashboard.
I have plotted the persentages valueboxes of positive, negative and neutral tweets.

```
valueBoxOutput("positivePercent",width = 3)

output$positivePercent <- renderValueBox({

    positivePercent <- round((nrow(positive)*100)/total)

    valueBox(
      value = paste(positivePercent, "%"),
      subtitle = "Positive", 
      color = "green",
      icon = icon("thumbs-up")
    )
  })
```

And I have shown what are the positive tweets using

```
tabItem(tabName = "pTweets",
      h2(HTML("<center><b><span style='color: green'>Positive</span> Tweets <i></i></b></center>")),

      tableOutput("positivitweets")
```

Now here I would like when I click that percentage value box then it should show positive tweets below of that box.

I am completely new to HTML and JAVASCRIPT,started to learn.

Comment: Ok.so its all about reputation points.

Comment: M.C stackoverflow

Comment: If dont have much points then i dont get any help from stackoverflow..r8.